# Unable to add text to XML file without error

Tags: python, xml, tkinter

I've been working on a simple python program to add 3 `SubElement`s to a xml file. I keep running into an error I'm not quite sure how to fix.

`TypeError: cannot serialize <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0347CAD8> (type StringVar)`

Here is the python code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


#Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("XML")
root.geometry("300x200")


frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
frame.pack()


#Button Action Adding XML to Mod7XML.xml
def click_button1():
    tree = et.parse('Mod7XML.xml')
    rootXML = tree.getroot()

    countryXML = et.SubElement(rootXML, 'country')

    nameXML = et.SubElement(countryXML, 'name')
    nameXML.text=name1

    populationXML = et.SubElement(countryXML, 'population')
    populationXML.text=population1

    continentXML = et.SubElement(countryXML, 'continent')
    continentXML.text=continent1

    tree.write('Mod7XML.xml')


#Label1
label1 = ttk.Label(frame, text="name")
label1.pack()

#TextEntry1
name1 = tk.StringVar()
name1Entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=name1)
name1Entry.pack()

#Label2
label2 = ttk.Label(frame, text="population")
label2.pack()

#TextEntry2
population1 = tk.StringVar()
population1Entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=population1)
population1Entry.pack()

#Label3
label3 = ttk.Label(frame, text="continent")
label3.pack()

#TextEntry3
continent1 = tk.StringVar()
continent1Entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=continent1)
continent1Entry.pack()

#Button1
button1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="Add XML data", command=click_button1)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and my xml file:

```xml
<nations>
     <country>
          <name>France</name>
          <population>66.99</population>
          <continent>Europe</continent>
     </country>
</nations>
```

When I run my python program, it changes the xml line 7, the last line, to `<country><name>`, instead of adding the three sub elements.

Comment: `tkinter.StringVar`s aren't strings. I think you need `nameXML.text=name1.get()` to retrieve the string value it contains.

Comment: Read up on [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your error is that you can't use directly a variable with a StringVar() content. To retreive it's value you have to access it's `.get()` method. Here's how it would look like:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


#Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("XML")
root.geometry("300x200")


frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 10 10")
frame.pack()


#Button Action Adding XML to Mod7XML.xml
def click_button1():
    tree = et.parse('Mod7XML.xml')
    rootXML = tree.getroot()

    countryXML = et.SubElement(rootXML, 'country')

    nameXML = et.SubElement(countryXML, 'name')
    nameXML.text = name1.get()

    populationXML = et.SubElement(countryXML, 'population')
    populationXML.text = population1.get()

    continentXML = et.SubElement(countryXML, 'continent')
    continentXML.text = continent1.get()

    tree.write('Mod7XML.xml')


#Label1
label1 = ttk.Label(frame, text="name")
label1.pack()

#TextEntry1
name1 = tk.StringVar()
name1Entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=name1)
name1Entry.pack()

#Label2
label2 = ttk.Label(frame, text="population")
label2.pack()

#TextEntry2
population1 = tk.StringVar()
population1Entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=population1)
population1Entry.pack()

#Label3
label3 = ttk.Label(frame, text="continent")
label3.pack()

#TextEntry3
continent1 = tk.StringVar()
continent1Entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=25, textvariable=continent1)
continent1Entry.pack()

#Button1
button1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="Add XML data", command=click_button1)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Finding information about `tkinter` isn't as straightforoward as other parts of the Standard Library. I haven't written a lot GUI application with [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) but if you want a good introduction to it you can look at [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/index.html) where I had a lot of information as a beginner in Tk.

Bonus: I tried to push things further. (Programming is making your life harder now so that it could be easier later ). Here's how it could look like:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

class Country_info_requester(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, file_input, file_output=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("XML")
        self.geometry("300x200")

        self.file_input = file_input
        self.file_output = file_input if file_output is None else file_output

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        background = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(10, 10, 10, 10))
        background.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="NSEW")

        info_requested = ('name', 'population', 'continent')
        self.values = {info: tk.StringVar() for info in info_requested}

        for (current_row, (current_info, current_variable)) in enumerate(self.values.items()):
            current_requester = self.Value_requester(background, current_info, current_variable)
            current_requester.grid(column=0, row=current_row)
            background.rowconfigure(current_row, weight=1)
        background.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        add_button = ttk.Button(background, text="Add XML data", command=self.add_requested)
        add_button.grid(column=0, row=current_row + 1)
        background.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        background.rowconfigure(current_row, weight=1)

    def add_requested(self):
        tree = et.parse(self.file_input)
        root_XML = tree.getroot()

        country_XML = et.SubElement(root_XML, 'country')

        for (info, variable) in self.values.items():
            info_XML = et.SubElement(country_XML, info)
            info_XML.text = variable.get()

        tree.write(self.file_output)

    class Value_requester(ttk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, master, value_requested, string_variable):
            super().__init__(master)

            label = ttk.Label(self, text=value_requested)
            label.grid(column=0, row=0)

            entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, textvariable=string_variable)
            entry.grid(column=0, row=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Country_info_requester('Mod7XML.xml')
    root.mainloop()
```